# Minimum files for Atmega1284p AVR-GCC?

Tags: avr, avr-gcc, blink

does someone have the minimum setup (ie. a 1284p `Makefile` and an example `blink.c`) for an ATMega1284p and AVR-GCC? I seem to be stuck setting things up with using the Arduino IDE and I'd like to test my breadbord setup with a simple blinking LED to rule out any mistakes here.

These is some information:

`Makefile`:

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# On command line:
# make all = Make software.
# make clean = Clean out built project files.
# make coff = Convert ELF to AVR COFF.
# make extcoff = Convert ELF to AVR Extended COFF.
# make program = Download the hex file to the device, using avrdude.
#                Please customize the avrdude settings below first!
# make debug = Start either simulavr or avarice as specified for debugging,
#              with avr-gdb or avr-insight as the front end for debugging.
# make filename.s = Just compile filename.c into the assembler code only.
# make filename.i = Create a preprocessed source file for use in submitting
#                   bug reports to the GCC project.
# To rebuild project do "make clean" then "make all".
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------


# MCU name
MCU = atmega1284p


# Processor frequency.
#     This will define a symbol, F_CPU, in all source code files equal to the
#     processor frequency. You can then use this symbol in your source code to
#     calculate timings. Do NOT tack on a 'UL' at the end, this will be done
#     automatically to create a 32-bit value in your source code.
#     Typical values are:
#         F_CPU =  1000000
#         F_CPU =  1843200
#         F_CPU =  2000000
#         F_CPU =  3686400
#         F_CPU =  4000000
#         F_CPU =  7372800
         F_CPU =  8000000
#         F_CPU = 11059200
#         F_CPU = 14745600
#         F_CPU = 16000000
#         F_CPU = 18432000
#         F_CPU = 20000000
#         F_CPU = 8000000


# Output format. (can be srec, ihex, binary)
FORMAT = ihex


# Target file name (without extension).
TARGET = main


# Object files directory
OBJDIR = obj


# List C source files here. (C dependencies are automatically generated.)
SRC = $(TARGET).c


# List C++ source files here. (C dependencies are automatically generated.)
CPPSRC =


# List Assembler source files here.
#     Make them always end in a capital .S.  Files ending in a lowercase .s
#     will not be considered source files but generated files (assembler
#     output from the compiler), and will be deleted upon "make clean"!
#     Even though the DOS/Win* filesystem matches both .s and .S the same,
#     it will preserve the spelling of the filenames, and gcc itself does
#     care about how the name is spelled on its command-line.
ASRC =


# Optimization level, can be [0, 1, 2, 3, s].
#     0 = turn off optimization. s = optimize for size.
#     (Note: 3 is not always the best optimization level. See avr-libc FAQ.)
OPT = s


# Debugging format.
#     Native formats for AVR-GCC's -g are dwarf-2 [default] or stabs.
#     AVR Studio 4.10 requires dwarf-2.
#     AVR [Extended] COFF format requires stabs, plus an avr-objcopy run.
DEBUG = dwarf-2


# List any extra directories to look for include files here.
#     Each directory must be seperated by a space.
#     Use forward slashes for directory separators.
#     For a directory that has spaces, enclose it in quotes.
EXTRAINCDIRS =


# Compiler flag to set the C Standard level.
#     c89   = "ANSI" C
#     gnu89 = c89 plus GCC extensions
#     c99   = ISO C99 standard (not yet fully implemented)
#     gnu99 = c99 plus GCC extensions
CSTANDARD = -std=gnu99


# Place -D or -U options here for C sources
CDEFS = -DF_CPU=$(F_CPU)UL


# Place -D or -U options here for C++ sources
CPPDEFS = -DF_CPU=$(F_CPU)UL
#CPPDEFS += -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
#CPPDEFS += -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS



#---------------- Compiler Options C ----------------
#  -g*:          generate debugging information
#  -O*:          optimization level
#  -f...:        tuning, see GCC manual and avr-libc documentation
#  -Wall...:     warning level
#  -Wa,...:      tell GCC to pass this to the assembler.
#    -adhlns...: create assembler listing
CFLAGS = -g$(DEBUG)
CFLAGS += $(CDEFS)
CFLAGS += -O$(OPT)
#CFLAGS += -mint8
#CFLAGS += -mshort-calls
CFLAGS += -funsigned-char
CFLAGS += -funsigned-bitfields
CFLAGS += -fpack-struct
CFLAGS += -fshort-enums
#CFLAGS += -fno-unit-at-a-time
CFLAGS += -Wall
CFLAGS += -Wstrict-prototypes
CFLAGS += -Wundef
#CFLAGS += -Wunreachable-code
#CFLAGS += -Wsign-compare
CFLAGS += -Wa,-adhlns=$(<:%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.lst)
CFLAGS += $(patsubst %,-I%,$(EXTRAINCDIRS))
CFLAGS += $(CSTANDARD)

# cts CFLAGS+= --combine -fwhole-program
CFLAGS+= -fwhole-program


#---------------- Compiler Options C++ ----------------
#  -g*:          generate debugging information
#  -O*:          optimization level
#  -f...:        tuning, see GCC manual and avr-libc documentation
#  -Wall...:     warning level
#  -Wa,...:      tell GCC to pass this to the assembler.
#    -adhlns...: create assembler listing
CPPFLAGS = -g$(DEBUG)
CPPFLAGS += $(CPPDEFS)
CPPFLAGS += -O$(OPT)
#CPPFLAGS += -mint8
#CPPFLAGS += -mshort-calls
CPPFLAGS += -funsigned-char
CPPFLAGS += -funsigned-bitfields
CPPFLAGS += -fpack-struct
CPPFLAGS += -fshort-enums
CPPFLAGS += -fno-exceptions
#CPPFLAGS += -fno-unit-at-a-time
CPPFLAGS += -Wall
#CPPFLAGS += -Wstrict-prototypes
CFLAGS += -Wundef
#CPPFLAGS += -Wunreachable-code
#CPPFLAGS += -Wsign-compare
CPPFLAGS += -Wa,-adhlns=$(<:%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/%.lst)
CPPFLAGS += $(patsubst %,-I%,$(EXTRAINCDIRS))
#CPPFLAGS += $(CSTANDARD)


#---------------- Assembler Options ----------------
#  -Wa,...:   tell GCC to pass this to the assembler.
#  -ahlms:    create listing
#  -gstabs:   have the assembler create line number information; note that
#             for use in COFF files, additional information about filenames
#             and function names needs to be present in the assembler source
#             files -- see avr-libc docs [FIXME: not yet described there]
ASFLAGS = -Wa,-adhlns=$(<:%.S=$(OBJDIR)/%.lst),-gstabs


#---------------- Library Options ----------------
# Minimalistic printf version
PRINTF_LIB_MIN = -Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_min

# Floating point printf version (requires MATH_LIB = -lm below)
PRINTF_LIB_FLOAT = -Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt

# If this is left blank, then it will use the Standard printf version.
PRINTF_LIB =
#PRINTF_LIB = $(PRINTF_LIB_MIN)
#PRINTF_LIB = $(PRINTF_LIB_FLOAT)


# Minimalistic scanf version
SCANF_LIB_MIN = -Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_min

# Floating point + %[ scanf version (requires MATH_LIB = -lm below)
SCANF_LIB_FLOAT = -Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_flt

# If this is left blank, then it will use the Standard scanf version.
SCANF_LIB =
#SCANF_LIB = $(SCANF_LIB_MIN)
#SCANF_LIB = $(SCANF_LIB_FLOAT)


MATH_LIB = -lm



#---------------- External Memory Options ----------------

# 64 KB of external RAM, starting after internal RAM (ATmega128!),
# used for variables (.data/.bss) and heap (malloc()).
#EXTMEMOPTS = -Wl,-Tdata=0x801100,--defsym=__heap_end=0x80ffff

# 64 KB of external RAM, starting after internal RAM (ATmega128!),
# only used for heap (malloc()).
#EXTMEMOPTS = -Wl,--defsym=__heap_start=0x801100,--defsym=__heap_end=0x80ffff

EXTMEMOPTS =



#---------------- Linker Options ----------------
#  -Wl,...:     tell GCC to pass this to linker.
#    -Map:      create map file
#    --cref:    add cross reference to  map file
LDFLAGS = -Wl,-Map=$(TARGET).map,--cref
LDFLAGS += $(EXTMEMOPTS)
LDFLAGS += $(PRINTF_LIB) $(SCANF_LIB) $(MATH_LIB)
#LDFLAGS += -T linker_script.x



#---------------- Programming Options (avrdude) ----------------

# Programming hardware: alf avr910 avrisp bascom bsd
# dt006 pavr picoweb pony-stk200 sp12 stk200 stk500
#
# Type: avrdude -c ?
# to get a full listing.
#
AVRDUDE_PROGRAMMER = dragon_pp


# com1 = serial port. Use lpt1 to connect to parallel port.
AVRDUDE_PORT = usb

AVRDUDE_WRITE_FLASH = -U flash:w:$(TARGET).hex
#AVRDUDE_WRITE_EEPROM = -U eeprom:w:$(TARGET).eep


# Uncomment the following if you want avrdude's erase cycle counter.
# Note that this counter needs to be initialized first using -Yn,
# see avrdude manual.
#AVRDUDE_ERASE_COUNTER = -y

# Uncomment the following if you do /not/ wish a verification to be
# performed after programming the device.
#AVRDUDE_NO_VERIFY = -V

# Increase verbosity level.  Please use this when submitting bug
# reports about avrdude. See <http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/avrdude>
# to submit bug reports.
#AVRDUDE_VERBOSE = -v -v

AVRDUDE_FLAGS = -p $(MCU) -P $(AVRDUDE_PORT) -c $(AVRDUDE_PROGRAMMER)
AVRDUDE_FLAGS += $(AVRDUDE_NO_VERIFY)
AVRDUDE_FLAGS += $(AVRDUDE_VERBOSE)
AVRDUDE_FLAGS += $(AVRDUDE_ERASE_COUNTER)



#---------------- Debugging Options ----------------

# For simulavr only - target MCU frequency.
DEBUG_MFREQ = $(F_CPU)

# Set the DEBUG_UI to either gdb or insight.
DEBUG_UI = gdb
# DEBUG_UI = insight

# Set the debugging back-end to either avarice, simulavr.
#DEBUG_BACKEND = avarice
DEBUG_BACKEND = simulavr

# GDB Init Filename.
GDBINIT_FILE = __avr_gdbinit

# When using avarice settings for the JTAG
JTAG_DEV = /dev/com1

# Debugging port used to communicate between GDB / avarice / simulavr.
DEBUG_PORT = 4242

# Debugging host used to communicate between GDB / avarice / simulavr, normally
#     just set to localhost unless doing some sort of crazy debugging when
#     avarice is running on a different computer.
DEBUG_HOST = localhost



#============================================================================


# Define programs and commands.
SHELL = sh
CC = avr-gcc
OBJCOPY = avr-objcopy
OBJDUMP = avr-objdump
SIZE = avr-size
NM = avr-nm
AVRDUDE = avrdude
REMOVE = rm -f
REMOVEDIR = rm -rf
COPY = cp
WINSHELL = cmd


# Define Messages
# English
MSG_ERRORS_NONE = Errors: none
MSG_BEGIN = -------- begin --------
MSG_END = --------  end  --------
MSG_SIZE_BEFORE = Size before:
MSG_SIZE_AFTER = Size after:
MSG_COFF = Converting to AVR COFF:
MSG_EXTENDED_COFF = Converting to AVR Extended COFF:
MSG_FLASH = Creating load file for Flash:
MSG_EEPROM = Creating load file for EEPROM:
MSG_EXTENDED_LISTING = Creating Extended Listing:
MSG_SYMBOL_TABLE = Creating Symbol Table:
MSG_LINKING = Linking:
MSG_COMPILING = Compiling C:
MSG_COMPILING_CPP = Compiling C++:
MSG_ASSEMBLING = Assembling:
MSG_CLEANING = Cleaning project:
MSG_CREATING_LIBRARY = Creating library:




# Define all object files.
OBJ = $(SRC:%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o) $(CPPSRC:%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/%.o) $(ASRC:%.S=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)

# Define all listing files.
LST = $(SRC:%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.lst) $(CPPSRC:%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/%.lst) $(ASRC:%.S=$(OBJDIR)/%.lst)


# Compiler flags to generate dependency files.
GENDEPFLAGS = -MD -MP -MF .dep/$(@F).d


# Combine all necessary flags and optional flags.
# Add target processor to flags.
ALL_CFLAGS = -mmcu=$(MCU) -I. $(CFLAGS) $(GENDEPFLAGS)
ALL_CPPFLAGS = -mmcu=$(MCU) -I. -x c++ $(CPPFLAGS) $(GENDEPFLAGS)
ALL_ASFLAGS = -mmcu=$(MCU) -I. -x assembler-with-cpp $(ASFLAGS)





# Default target.
all: begin gccversion sizebefore build sizeafter end

# Change the build target to build a HEX file or a library.
build: elf hex eep lss sym
#build: lib


elf: $(TARGET).elf
hex: $(TARGET).hex
eep: $(TARGET).eep
lss: $(TARGET).lss
sym: $(TARGET).sym
LIBNAME=lib$(TARGET).a
lib: $(LIBNAME)



# Eye candy.
# AVR Studio 3.x does not check make's exit code but relies on
# the following magic strings to be generated by the compile job.

begin:
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_BEGIN)

end:
    @echo $(MSG_END)
    @echo


# Display size of file.
HEXSIZE = $(SIZE) --target=$(FORMAT) $(TARGET).hex
ELFSIZE = $(SIZE) -A $(TARGET).elf
AVRMEM = avr-mem.sh $(TARGET).elf $(MCU)

sizebefore:
    @if test -f $(TARGET).elf; then echo; echo $(MSG_SIZE_BEFORE); $(ELFSIZE); \
    $(AVRMEM) 2>/dev/null; echo; fi

sizeafter:
    @if test -f $(TARGET).elf; then echo; echo $(MSG_SIZE_AFTER); $(ELFSIZE); \
    $(AVRMEM) 2>/dev/null; echo; fi



# Display compiler version information.
gccversion :
    @$(CC) --version



# Program the device.
program: $(TARGET).hex $(TARGET).eep
    $(AVRDUDE) $(AVRDUDE_FLAGS) $(AVRDUDE_WRITE_FLASH)
    $(AVRDUDE_WRITE_EEPROM)


# Generate avr-gdb config/init file which does the following:
#     define the reset signal, load the target file, connect to target, and set
#     a breakpoint at main().
gdb-config:
    @$(REMOVE) $(GDBINIT_FILE)
    @echo define reset >> $(GDBINIT_FILE)
    @echo SIGNAL SIGHUP >> $(GDBINIT_FILE)
    @echo end >> $(GDBINIT_FILE)
    @echo file $(TARGET).elf >> $(GDBINIT_FILE)
    @echo target remote $(DEBUG_HOST):$(DEBUG_PORT)  >> $(GDBINIT_FILE)
    ifeq ($(DEBUG_BACKEND),simulavr)
    @echo load  >> $(GDBINIT_FILE)
    endif
    @echo break main >> $(GDBINIT_FILE)

debug: gdb-config $(TARGET).elf
    ifeq ($(DEBUG_BACKEND), avarice)
    @echo Starting AVaRICE - Press enter when "waiting to connect" message displays.
    @$(WINSHELL) /c start avarice --jtag $(JTAG_DEV) --erase --program --file \
$(TARGET).elf $(DEBUG_HOST):$(DEBUG_PORT)
    @$(WINSHELL) /c pause

    else
    @$(WINSHELL) /c start simulavr --gdbserver --device $(MCU) --clock-freq \
    $(DEBUG_MFREQ) --port $(DEBUG_PORT)
    endif
    @$(WINSHELL) /c start avr-$(DEBUG_UI) --command=$(GDBINIT_FILE)




# Convert ELF to COFF for use in debugging / simulating in AVR Studio or VMLAB.
    COFFCONVERT = $(OBJCOPY) --debugging
    COFFCONVERT += --change-section-address .data-0x800000
    COFFCONVERT += --change-section-address .bss-0x800000
    COFFCONVERT += --change-section-address .noinit-0x800000
    COFFCONVERT += --change-section-address .eeprom-0x810000



coff: $(TARGET).elf
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_COFF) $(TARGET).cof
    $(COFFCONVERT) -O coff-avr $< $(TARGET).cof


extcoff: $(TARGET).elf
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_EXTENDED_COFF) $(TARGET).cof
    $(COFFCONVERT) -O coff-ext-avr $< $(TARGET).cof



# Create final output files (.hex, .eep) from ELF output file.
%.hex: %.elf
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_FLASH) $@
    $(OBJCOPY) -O $(FORMAT) -R .eeprom $< $@

%.eep: %.elf
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_EEPROM) $@
    -$(OBJCOPY) -j .eeprom --set-section-flags=.eeprom="alloc,load" \
--change-section-lma .eeprom=0 -O $(FORMAT) $< $@

# Create extended listing file from ELF output file.
%.lss: %.elf
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_EXTENDED_LISTING) $@
    $(OBJDUMP) -h -S $< > $@

# Create a symbol table from ELF output file.
%.sym: %.elf
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_SYMBOL_TABLE) $@
    $(NM) -n $< > $@



# Create library from object files.
.SECONDARY : $(TARGET).a
.PRECIOUS : $(OBJ)
%.a: $(OBJ)
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_CREATING_LIBRARY) $@
    $(AR) $@ $(OBJ)


# Link: create ELF output file from object files.
.SECONDARY : $(TARGET).elf
.PRECIOUS : $(OBJ)
%.elf: $(OBJ)
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_LINKING) $@
    $(CC) $(ALL_CFLAGS) $^ --output $@ $(LDFLAGS)


# Compile: create object files from C source files.
$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_COMPILING) $<
    $(CC) -c $(ALL_CFLAGS) $< -o $@


# Compile: create object files from C++ source files.
$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.cpp
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_COMPILING_CPP) $<
    $(CC) -c $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@


# Compile: create assembler files from C source files.
%.s : %.c
    $(CC) -S $(ALL_CFLAGS) $< -o $@


# Compile: create assembler files from C++ source files.
%.s : %.cpp
    $(CC) -S $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@


# Assemble: create object files from assembler source files.
$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.S
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_ASSEMBLING) $<
    $(CC) -c $(ALL_ASFLAGS) $< -o $@


# Create preprocessed source for use in sending a bug report.
%.i : %.c
    $(CC) -E -mmcu=$(MCU) -I. $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@


# Target: clean project.
clean: begin clean_list end

clean_list :
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_CLEANING)
    $(REMOVE) $(TARGET).hex
    $(REMOVE) $(TARGET).eep
    $(REMOVE) $(TARGET).cof
    $(REMOVE) $(TARGET).elf
    $(REMOVE) $(TARGET).map
    $(REMOVE) $(TARGET).sym
    $(REMOVE) $(TARGET).lss
    $(REMOVEDIR) $(OBJDIR)
    $(REMOVE) $(SRC:.c=.s)
    $(REMOVE) $(SRC:.c=.d)
    $(REMOVEDIR) .dep


# Create object files directory
$(shell mkdir $(OBJDIR) 2>/dev/null)


# Include the dependency files.
-include $(shell mkdir .dep 2>/dev/null) $(wildcard .dep/*)


# Listing of phony targets.
.PHONY : all begin finish end sizebefore sizeafter gccversion \
build elf hex eep lss sym coff extcoff \
clean clean_list program debug gdb-config
```

main.c

```
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
int main (void) {
  DDRB  = 0xff;
  while(1) {
    PORTB |= (1<<PB1);    //Bit setzen - set bit
    _delay_ms(500);       // halbe sekunde warten - wait half a second
    PORTB &= ~(1<<PB1);   // Bit loeschen - reset bit
    _delay_ms(500);       // halbe sekunde warten - wait half a second
  }
 return 0;
}
```

*The "build process" (well, that's a little overstated)*:

```
$ make

-------- begin --------
avr-gcc (GCC) 4.7.2
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Dies ist freie Software; die Kopierbedingungen stehen in den Quellen. Es
gibt KEINE Garantie; auch nicht für MARKTGÄNGIGKEIT oder FÜR SPEZIELLE ZWECKE.


Size before:
main.elf  :
section          size      addr
.data               0   8388864
.text             214         0
.stab            1848         0
.stabstr          231         0
.comment           17         0
.debug_aranges     32         0
.debug_info       363         0
.debug_abbrev     225         0
.debug_line       222         0
.debug_frame       36         0
.debug_str        201         0
.debug_ranges      16         0
Total            3405




Size after:
main.elf  :
section          size      addr
.data               0   8388864
.text             214         0
.stab            1848         0
.stabstr          231         0
.comment           17         0
.debug_aranges     32         0
.debug_info       363         0
.debug_abbrev     225         0
.debug_line       222         0
.debug_frame       36         0
.debug_str        201         0
.debug_ranges      16         0
Total            3405



-------- end --------
```

*Uploading everything to the ATMega1284p through the AVR Dragon using HVPP*:

```
$ avrdude -c dragon_pp -P usb -p m1284p –u –U flash:w:main.hex

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.15s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e9705

avrdude: safemode: Fuses OK
avrdude: jtagmkII_close(): bad response to GO command: RSP_ILLEGAL_EMULATOR_MODE

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

This seems complete, but does not yield a `blink`on PORTB PB1 (or any other pin for that).
If I have forgotten anything that could be of help, please let me know.

Comment: Everything takes work & effort...

Comment: Do you have `avrdude`?

Comment: Well, I figured the examples I had aren't necessary, but here (see above) we go. Yes, I do have avrdude and the gcc-avr tools as do I have libc-avr (this is on OS X 10.8).

Comment: @Chrisitian Ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my general purpose Makefile for use on Linux. Haven't tested it on Windows or iOS. Only the first few variables normally need to be edited.

```
baudrate=19200
src=project
avrType=atmega1284p
avrFreq=20000000
programmerDev=/dev/ttyUSB003
programmerType=arduino

cflags=-g -DF_CPU=$(avrFreq) -Wall -Os -Werror -Wextra

memoryTypes=calibration eeprom efuse flash fuse hfuse lfuse lock signature application apptable boot prodsig usersig

.PHONY: backup clean disassemble dumpelf edit eeprom elf flash fuses help hex makefile object program

SHELL := /bin/bash

ifdef baudrate
    baud=-b$(baudrate)
else
    baud=
endif

help:
        @echo 'backup           Read all known memory types from controller and write it into a file. Available memory types: $(memoryTypes)'
        @echo 'clean            Delete automatically created files.'
        @echo 'disassemble      Compile source code, then disassemble object file to mnemonics.'
        @echo 'dumpelf          Dump the contents of the .elf file. Useful for information purposes only.'
        @echo 'edit             Edit the .cpp source file.'
        @echo 'eeprom           Extract EEPROM data from .elf file and program the device with it.'
        @echo 'elf              Create $(src).elf'
        @echo 'flash            Program $(src).hex to controller flash memory.'
        @echo 'fuses            Extract FUSES data from .elf file and program the device with it.'
        @echo 'help             Show this text.'
        @echo 'hex              Create all hex files for flash, eeprom and fuses.'
        @echo 'object           Create $(src).o'
        @echo 'program          Do all programming to controller.'

edit:
    [[ ! -f $(src).cpp ]] && echo '// VERSION: ' > $(src).cpp
    vi '$(src).cpp' -s <( printf ":set number\n:1 s/^\/\/ VERSION: .*$$/\/\/ VERSION: $$(date)/g\n" )

makefile:
        vi Makefile


clean: 
        rm $(src).elf $(src).eeprom.hex $(src).fuses.hex $(src).lfuse.hex $(src).hfuse.hex $(src).efuse.hex $(src).flash.hex $(src).o
        date

object:
        avr-gcc $(cflags) -mmcu=$(avrType) -Wa,-ahlmns=$(src).lst -c -o $(src).o $(src).cpp 

elf: object
        avr-gcc $(cflags) -mmcu=$(avrType) -o $(src).elf $(src).o
        chmod a-x $(src).elf 2>&1

hex:    elf
        avr-objcopy -j .text -j .data -O ihex $(src).elf $(src).flash.hex
        avr-objcopy -j .eeprom --set-section-flags=.eeprom="alloc,load" --change-section-lma .eeprom=0 -O ihex $(src).elf $(src).eeprom.hex
        avr-objcopy -j .fuse -O ihex $(src).elf $(src).fuses.hex --change-section-lma .fuse=0
        srec_cat $(src).fuses.hex -Intel -crop 0x00 0x01 -offset  0x00 -O $(src).lfuse.hex -Intel
        srec_cat $(src).fuses.hex -Intel -crop 0x01 0x02 -offset -0x01 -O $(src).hfuse.hex -Intel
        srec_cat $(src).fuses.hex -Intel -crop 0x02 0x03 -offset -0x02 -O $(src).efuse.hex -Intel

disassemble: elf
        avr-objdump -s -j .fuse $(src).elf
        avr-objdump -C -d $(src).elf 2>&1

eeprom: hex
        #avrdude -p$(avrType) -c$(programmerType) -P$(programmerDev) $(baud) -v -U eeprom:w:$(src).eeprom.hex
        date

fuses: hex
        avrdude -p$(avrType) -c$(programmerType) -P$(programmerDev) $(baud) -v -U lfuse:w:$(src).lfuse.hex
        #avrdude -p$(avrType) -c$(programmerType) -P$(programmerDev) $(baud) -v -U hfuse:w:$(src).hfuse.hex
        #avrdude -p$(avrType) -c$(programmerType) -P$(programmerDev) $(baud) -v -U efuse:w:$(src).efuse.hex
        date

dumpelf: elf
        avr-objdump -s -h $(src).elf

program: flash eeprom fuses

flash: hex
        avrdude -p$(avrType) -c$(programmerType) -P$(programmerDev) $(baud) -v -U flash:w:$(src).flash.hex
        date

backup:
        @for memory in $(memoryTypes); do \
                avrdude -p $(avrType) -c$(programmerType) -P$(programmerDev) $(baud) -v -U $$memory:r:./$(avrType).$$memory.hex:i; \
        done
```

Compiling is configured in such a way that any warning will throw an error and exit. However it may sometimes seem a nuisance, it is actually a good programming practice.

I usually create a directory with the name of my project, eg. `blink`. Then in that directory I copy my generic `Makefile` and I create `project.cpp`. I always use the same name for the `cpp` file, so I don't have to change my `Makefile`

To compile and flash `project.cpp` you just type `make flash`. If you want more information about the other options in the makefile type `make help`.

What happens when you type `make flash` is:

- the dependency `hex` is executed;
- `hex` in turn has a dependency of its own: `elf`, which is executed;
- `elf` has a dependency as well: `object`, which is therefore executed;
- `object` has no dependencies, so it executes the commands on the following line: `avr-gcc ...`;
- when the `object` dependency is fulfilled, control is given back to `elf` which executes the commands on the lines below it;
- control is given back to `hex` ... ;
- control is given back to flash ... .

If you are not planning to use this Makefile for burning the fuses, you can comment out the `srec_cat` lines, a command that often needs to be installed (`apt-get install srecord` on Debian'like distributions).

Comment: Thanks, seems to be a very complete solution. The `eeprom : hex` and `fuses : hex` parts are unused, right? what are the `date` lines at the end of make-parts for?

Comment: I don't like to accidentally program fuses/eeprom, so I commented out some of the lines that I haven't tested/needed yet. They should work, just never needed them yet. The `date` lines just print current date and time on the terminal so I know when the last moment was I executed the code when I scroll back.

Comment: For future updates: http://git.linformatronics.nl/gitweb/?p=makefile;a=summary

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have `avrdude` you may run these simple commands to upload a `HEX` file to your AVR.

This command will compile your `.c` or `.cpp` file into a `.elf` file:

1: `avr-gcc -mmcu=atmega1284p -Wall -Os -o src.elf blink.c`

The `-mmcu=` part specifies your part so that it could compile your `.c` file for your ATmega1284p

And you can see clearly that you can change the name of the `.elf` file or the input file

This command will parse your `.elf` file into a `.hex` file:

2: `avr-objcopy -j .text -j .data -O ihex src.elf src.hex`

And as you see again, you can change the input files (`src.elf` = input & `src.hex` = output)

And this command will upload the `.hex` file to your AVR:

3: `avrdude -p m1284p -c arduino -P /dev/ttyACM0 -b 9600 -U flash:w:src.hex`

The `-p` part specifies the part which you will program

The `-c` tag shows what type of programmer you will use

The `-P` tag shows where your programmer is located, this tag is optional, but if you get any errors on `avrdude` not finding your AVR, you should add in the `-P` tag, if you do not know where your device is located, open the Arduino IDE, and try uploading a file to it without your Arduino plugged in. It should say it could not find your device in so and so directory.

The `-b` command specifies the baud rate between the programmer and the computer

The `-U` uploads the `.hex` file to your AVR

I have found using these commands with all the tags and variables most helpful and I don't get many errors too often either.

If you get any errors, feel free to comment and I will help you out. I don't like Makefiles, I have a hard time with them. Hope that helps!

P.S.
I have made a `Java` 'makefile' that uploads everything for you in the simplest way, if your interested please note below.

***EDIT:*** *(Thanks Christian)*

Please put this in your `.c` or `.cpp` file:

```
#define F_CPU ... // The clock rate of your AVR, usually measured in MHz
```

Comment: Thanks! I amended your gcc-avr commanline with the `-DF_CPU=8000000` parameter because avr-gcc complained about it missing. And yes, I'd very much like to take a look at your Java makefile!

Comment: @Christian Ooops! I forgot to add that in, I would rather put in this in your `.c` or `.cpp`: `#define F_CPU ...` Thanks for that! I'll add that in!

Comment: @Christian Ok, I hope you know bash well as it says in your profile, join me for a chat here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering as soon as you can, i'll help you get is all set up. The makefile is pretty awesome!